# What is the technical term for the $n$-dimensional generalization of the unit interval?

Tags: terminology

What is the technical term for an $n$-dimensional generalization of the unit interval $[0, 1]$?  Would we call an $n = 1,2,3,...$ dimensional generalization of the unit interval an $n$-cube?

Comment: Yes. This is a sensible and widely-recognized name.

Comment: @ncmathsadist Would it also be reasonable to call it an $R^n$ unit interval?  The basis of my question is seeing this in print.

Comment: I'd refer to it as a "cube" or a "cell."

Comment: I have seen it generalized as an n-dimensional interval, described as the set of points $x_; i=1,2,..,n$ with, e.g., $a_i < x< b_i$, where, of course, you can also have $a_i \leq x_i <b_i$, etc., i.e., closed, semi-open, etc.

Comment: Most real analysis textbooks will call it an $n$-cube or $n$-rectangle. It comes into play a lot, since the supnorm is equivalent to the Euclidean norm in R and it is sometimes more convenient to do analysis on cubes instead of balls. Integration comes to mind...

Answer (score 3):

Since you said you wanted to generalize the *unit* interval, you should probably refer to the "*unit* $n$-cube". You can see that this terminology is used with [a google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22unit%20n-cube%22), which pulls up papers like [this one](http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.3875).